# dynamic programming: coin change

Tags: c++, coin-change

I have as an input:

1. the number of testcases
2. an amount of money

As output I need:

1. The number different coins we have and the value of each coin.

The program should determine whether there is a solution or not, so the output should be either a "yes" or a "no".

I wrote the program using dynamic programming, but it only works when I enter one testcase at a time If i write let's say 200 testcases at once, the output isn't always right.

I'm assuming that I have an issue with incorrectly saved state between test cases. 
My question is, how could I solve this problem? I'm only asking for some advice.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

#define max_muenzwert 1000

  using namespace std;


  int coin[10];//max. 10 coins
  int d[max_muenzwert][10];//max value of a coin und max. number of coins

  int tabelle(int s,int k)//computes table
  {   
    if(d[s][k]!=-1) return d[s][k];
    d[s][k]=0; 

    for(int i=k;i<=9&&s>=coin[i];i++)
      d[s][k]+=tabelle(s-coin[i],i);


    return d[s][k];
 }

 int main()

 {
    int t;
    for(cin>>t;t>0;t--)//number of testcases

     {        

                int n;   //value we are searching   
           scanf("%d",&n)==1;             
          int n1;              

    cin>>n1;//how many coins

    for (int n2=0; n2<n1; n2++)
    {
        cin>>coin[n2];//value of coins
        }

    memset(d,-1,sizeof(d));//set table to -1

    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
             d[0][i]=1;//set only first row to 1 
             }

      if(tabelle(n,0)>0) //if there's a solution
      {
                    cout<<"yes"<<endl;

                    }
      else //no solution
      {
           cout<<"no"<<endl;

      }





      }
      //system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that test cases are running together? For instance, your `scanf("%d",...)` is going to pick up the first continuous string of decimal digits.

Comment: I hate it when people ask a question then do not care about it! Did my answer fixed your problem? :)

Comment: @sowrov sorry for not answering, I found an other way to do it and I pretty much deleted this code. But if you want to see the working code, I could post it if want to see it. And thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you have variable number of coins, which you are taking input using this line: `cin>>n1;//how many coins`. But in the `tabelle` method you are always looping through `0 - 9`, which is wrong. You should only loop through `0 - n1`. Try this test case:

```
2
10
2
2 5

10
1
9
```

For the second test set your answer should be `no` but your program will say `yes` as it will find 5 in the second element of your coin array.

Comment: Btw, Either use only scanf or only cin but not both on the same project/source. Because they are not compatible, `cin` object most probably use buffered reading which read out input before you need it and thus `scanf` will not be able to read anything from the input source.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=k;i<=9&&s>=coin[i];i++)
  d[s][k]+=tabelle(s-coin[i],i);
```

Here, if `coin[i] < s`, then the entire loop will break, while you only need to skip this coin.

P.S. Please bother yourself with proper code formatting.